# Pivot Table from Three Tables without Aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Apologies for my lack of knowledge on this, I've researched here and elsewhere but have hit a brick wall (my brain).  I'm trying to display the rates for a villa in a table like this:

```
                SPRING     SUMMER     FALL      WINTER    MAX GUESTS
2 Rooms         $343       $288       $389      $467      2
3 Rooms         $456       $415       $536      $756      4
Whole Villa     $809       $789       $906      $1023     6
```

I assume that PIVOT is the answer to my woes.  I'm using SQL Server 2008 on MS Server 2008 R2

The seasons, packages and prices are stored in 3 tables like this:

```
CONFIGURATIONS
--------------
configurationID
configurationName
maximumGuests

SEASONS
-------
seasonID
seasonName

CONFIGURATIONSEASONRATES
------------------------
seasonID
configurationID
price
```

I got as far as this based on the examples I've been able to find:

```
SELECT 'Packages', 'Summer', 'Winter', 'Christmas', 'Tropical'

FROM

(SELECT     ACCOMMODATION_configurations.configurationName, price
FROM         ACCOMMODATION_configurations INNER JOIN
                      ACCOMMODATION_configurationSeasonRates ON 
                      ACCOMMODATION_configurations.configurationID = ACCOMMODATION_configurationSeasonRates.configurationID INNER JOIN
                      ACCOMMODATION_seasons ON ACCOMMODATION_configurationSeasonRates.seasonID = ACCOMMODATION_seasons.seasonID) as somethingNice

PIVOT (sum(price) for ACCOMMODATION_configurations.configurationName IN (['Summer'],['Winter'],['Christmas'],['Tropical'])) as anyThing
```

But I get an error saying

> **The column prefix 'ACCOMMODATION_configurations' does not match with a table name or alias used in the query**

I then tried replacing **SELECT 'Packages'** with **SELECT ACCOMMODATION_configurations.configurationName** but then I am told that:

> SELECT ACCOMMODATION_configurations.configurationName  cannot be bound

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of your PIVOT syntax you need to remove the `ACCOMMODATION_configurations`.  Also remove the single quotes around the values in the `FOR` and you need to add the `Packages` column to the inner select.

So the code will be:

```
-- this select will display the packages and the seasons
SELECT Packages, Summer, Winter, Christmas, Tropical
FROM
(
  -- add Packages to this select list
  SELECT Packages, ac.configurationName, price
  FROM ACCOMMODATION_configurations ac
  INNER JOIN ACCOMMODATION_configurationSeasonRates sr
    ON ac.configurationID = sr.configurationID 
  INNER JOIN ACCOMMODATION_seasons s
    ON sr.seasonID = s.seasonID
) as somethingNice
PIVOT 
(
  sum(price) 
  for configurationName IN ([Summer],[Winter],[Christmas],[Tropical])
) as anyThing
```

Edit, based on your comment it seems like you might want:

```
-- this select will display the packages and the seasons
SELECT Packages, Summer, Winter, Christmas, Tropical
FROM
(
  SELECT ac.configurationName as Packages, price, seasonName
  FROM ACCOMMODATION_configurations ac
  INNER JOIN ACCOMMODATION_configurationSeasonRates sr
    ON ac.configurationID = sr.configurationID 
  INNER JOIN ACCOMMODATION_seasons s
    ON sr.seasonID = s.seasonID
) as somethingNice
PIVOT 
(
  sum(price) 
  for seasonName IN ([Summer],[Winter],[Christmas],[Tropical])
) as anyThing
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking a look at this!  I'm getting an error which is down to me not being clear - 'Packages' is just an arbitrary word (not a real column) that I used for the heading of the first column (which contains 'configurationName' in the rows).  In my example above I left that blank in the grid but wasn't sure if it was possible.

How do you manage to absorb all this stuff and process it so fast?!

Comment: (Forgot to say, the error I'm getting is 'Invalid column name 'Packages')

Comment: @MrFett Is the `Summer`, etc a Season or a configuration name?

Comment: 'Summer' is a season name.  This did the trick wonderfully - many many thanks!  :-)

Comment: I hope you don't me asking this additional query - in this context, presumably 'SUM' does nothing (because its being applied to a single row), it's just used so that there is an aggregate function called (required by PIVOT)

Comment: @MrFett The `sum()` is used to aggregate the `price` across each column for every `package`.  The PIVOT is just a function that does the same thing as using an aggregate with a `CASE`.

Comment: Thanks again.  At some point I also need to work out how to have the columns (seasons) dynamically updated, I'll create a separate question for that however!  On another note, I have a future complex project coming up, are you available for hire?

Comment: Probably the first job offer I've seen posted in the comments.